# How to change value of a variable by changing its ascii value?

Tags: c

```
  /*change the case of each alphabet in this String. */ 
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>

int main()
{
char a[100],b,c;
int i;
scanf("%s",a);
int len=strlen(a);
for(i=0;i<len;i++)

    {    c=a[i];
         b='c';
        if(b<91)
         b=b+32;
        else if(b>96)
          b=b-32;
        'c'=b;   /*error*/
         a[i]=c;
}

printf("%s",a);    

 return 0;
}
```

I wanted to change each variable of string to its corresponding uppercase or lowercase (eg. input: adsE
                            output: ADSe)
so i tried it by changing ASCII value of variable,
but I am not able to put the new ASCII value to the original variable back.
how should I do it?

Comment: `'c'` is a literal value of type `int`.  You cannot assign to it, and it is not related to variable `c` in any meaningful way.

Comment: Additionally, although it is *likely* that your C implementation uses ASCII or an ASCII-compatible character encoding, C implementations are not required to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the variable `c` and character `'c'` are not related in anyway. You can assign to `c` like `c = 'a'` but you can't assign to `'c'` - just like you can't assign to a number, e.g. `9 = 42` will fail.

However, there is no need for using the variables `b` and `c`. You can simply operate directly on `a`. Like

```
    if (a[i] < 91)
         a[i] = a[i] + 32;
    else if (a[i] > 94)    // Hmm, should this be 96?
        a[i] = a[i] - 32;
```

You could improve the code like:

```
    if ((a[i] >= 'A') && (a[i] <= 'Z'))
         a[i] = a[i] + 32;
    else if ((a[i] >= 'a') && (a[i] <= 'z'))
        a[i] = a[i] - 32;
```

Comment: You **can** but you **shouldn't** do this. C is not tied to ASCII. And while it's usually reasonable to assume that it is, it is much better to use the standard functions `isalpha()`, `tolower()`, and `toupper()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you

```
#include <ctype.h>
```

then you can use the `toupper()` or `tolower()` functions to convert a character to upper/lower-case. You may also test the case with `isupper()` and `islower()`.

For example:

```
if      (islower(ch)) ch = toupper(ch);
else if (isupper(ch)) ch = tolower(ch);
```